# For kernel module makefile: Use another name for the makefile and using command line parameter

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel

I have Kernel module sources (for arm) and I would like to compile two different drivers from the same source.

The kernel in compiled with 2 source files and with cross compile.

```
MODULE_MAME = modulename

SRCS = drv/source.c lib/libsrc.c

OBJS =  $(SRCS:.c=.o)

obj-m += $(MODULE_MAME).o
$(MODULE_MAME)-y = $(OBJS)

KDIR  := /mykermelsources/
PWD   := $(shell pwd)

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR)  ARCH=arm M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR)  ARCH=arm M=$(PWD) clean
```

In one command, I would like to compile 2 modules.

#### **Two choices:**

- Keeping 3 different Makefiles, one main that will call both other makefiles. One problem with this, I cannot make it working. `make -f makefilediff` or `make --makefile=makefilediff` give me an error.

Log:

```
make -C /mykermelsources/  ARCH=arm M=/home/mychardriver/ modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/mykermelsources'
scripts/Makefile.build:44: /home/mychardriver/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/mychardriver//Makefile'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/mychardriver/] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mykermelsources'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

- Transmitting command line parameter but it doesn't work. `make SIDE=1`

Seems the `SIDE` parameter/variable is never transmitted.

```
ifeq ($(SIDE),1)
MODULE_MAME = modulename_11
else
MODULE_MAME = modulename_22
endif

SRCS = drv/source.c lib/libsrc.c

OBJS =  $(SRCS:.c=.o)a

obj-m += $(MODULE_MAME).o
$(MODULE_MAME)-y = $(OBJS)

KDIR  := /mykermelsources/
PWD   := $(shell pwd)

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR)  ARCH=arm M=$(PWD) SIDE=$(SIDE) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR)  ARCH=arm M=$(PWD) clean
```

#### How can I build 2 kernel modules from same multiple source files ?

Comment: Fix the error you have first.

Comment: Which one ? `scripts/Makefile.build:44: /home/mychardriver//Makefile: No such file or directory` ? it shouldn't search for a `Makefile` but for `makefilediff` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just faced this issue, and this is what I did:

For each `moduleX` you want to build, write a `Kbuild_moduleX` with the targets. Example:

```
obj-$(MODULE) += MODULE.o
MODULE-y := source.o
```

Then, in your `Makefile_moduleX`, do:

```
all:
   cp Kbuild_moduleX Kbuild
   make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules
   rm Kbuild
```

This works because the kernel scripts will give Kbuild priority over reading Makefile.

To compile, do `make -f Makefile_moduleX`

Is it pretty? No. Does it work? Yes.

Comment: It's 5years old then I don't really need it anymore but good for reference and in the future, who knows. Does it work with a custom parameter like in my question?

Comment: I added because of that, who knows if someone else will need it in the future. It does work with parameters normally, I'm passing a define to one of the module and not passing to another: `make CFLAGS_MODULE='-DMYFLAG=1'` in one of the Makefiles.